# Memory error with type L"" in Win32

Tags: win32gui, win32-process, tchar, wm-paint, strcat-s

Here's the code for my paint method in my Win32 project:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    _tcscat_s(greeting, sizeof(greeting), LoadedFile);
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    TextOut(hdc,  
        5, 5,  
        greeting, _tcslen(greeting));

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
```

I am consistently getting the error that either the stack around *greeting* or around *ps* is corrupted. To be clear, *greeting* is initialized like:

```
TCHAR greeting[100] = _T("Welcome! Your file is ");
```

And `LoadedFile` is initialized like this:

```
TCHAR LoadedFile[100];
LoadedFile[0] = 0;
```

`LoadedFile` is not yet changed by anything, so it shouldn't be adding anything to `greeting`. I've tried things like

```
sizeof(greeting) + 1
```

Which just shifts the error. Not sure what's wrong here.

Edit: Without the `_tcscat_s()`, call the window loads normally

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the problem, even though I don't really understand why the solution works. I just changed

```
 _tcscat_s(greeting, sizeof(greeting), LoadedFile);
```

to

```
_tcscat_s(greeting, 100, LoadedFile);
```

Comment: The second parameter of `_tcscat_s()` expects the buffer size in **characters**, but you are expressing it in **bytes** instead.  When `TCHAR` is `wchar_t`, `sizeof(TCHAR)` is 2, so `sizeof(greeting)` is 200, giving `_tcscat_s()` permission to go out the bounds.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually very helpful

Comment: For static arrays, you can use things like [`_countof()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175773.aspx), `ARRAYSIZE()`, etc, if your compiler supports them.  They will give you the array size in elements instead of bytes.